# Is there a quest to be triggered once one was moved to Beast Stone in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

So I was clearing out a ship wreck and decided take a nap in a nearby sleeping roll to feel well-rested, when suddenly I woke up working on some temple at the Beast Stone with bunch of cultists.

The Temple of Miraak is close nearby featuring a Tree Stone. Interacting with the stones just makes me their tool again to work at the temple. I tried talking to the cultists but they all spout out mystical one liners.

Is there a quest involved with those cultists, and if so how do I trigger it? Or was this just a random encounter?

Comment: I can't remember exactly how it happens, but you eventually get a quest to "activate" these stones, which summons monsters from Apocrypha. When you defeat them, you free everyone that's working on these stones.

Comment: @Ben According to [elderscrolls.wikia.com/](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonborn_(Quest)) I have to complete the quest [The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Horn_of_Jurgen_Windcaller) as then some cultists are said to attack me, triggering the main quest.

Comment: I believe so. You will need to start the main Dragonborn questline, and I remember the cleansing of these stones involves a shout of some kind.

Comment: Getting drafted into Miraak's redecoration project should only happen in Solstheim, but you haven't started the DB main quest yet? Are you using Alternate Start?

Comment: @KlausDraeger I don't use mods but play the vanilla game with all its official DLC. Yet I did start this play through with the whole intention of not visiting Whiterun at all in the beginning as I just wanted to see what can be done without doing the main quest at all. It turns out, quite a lot. In over 100 hours of gameplay I have one(!) finished main quest, namely the one where you flee Helgen Keep.

Comment: Sounds like you hit a bug then - you shouldn't get to Solstheim before the cultist attack. Ben's answer gives a good description of the relevant quest, but I wonder if you can do it, given that you shouldn't have any dragon souls yet to learn the shout. Is the fast travel marker for Skyrim available, just in case?

Comment: @KlausDraeger I found a ferry man who let me join for a ride if I pay 250 gold. When entering Solstheim, I was asked for my motivation, and all I could say was either "for work", or "none of your business". It seems alright. I think I have to start the main quest and wait for the cultists to attack me to trigger. That might take some while. Still go t plenty of things to do. (And yes, I have not killed a single dragon in Skyrim and hence have not collected any dragon soul nor do I know any dragon shout.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to start the [The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Horn_of_Jurgen_Windcaller) main quest one only gets from the Grey Beards, after having visited Whiterun, talking to the Jarl there, and being sent of the Grey Beards.

While trying to obtain the horn, I was told to go to Riverwood. There, I met two Cultists asking me if I was the Dragonborn, a fight ensued, and I got a note from their bodies that directed me to Solstheim.

In Solstheim, after asking around, I was sent to the Temple of Miraak, and this time Frea from the Skaal village appears, leading eventually to the quest to destroy all those stones.

Answer (score 4):

The Beast Stone is one of 4 markers (though there are 5 in total) that need to be [cleansed](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Cleansing_the_Stones) as a part of the main questline in the Dragonborn DLC. This is done with the [Bend Will](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Bend_Will) shout.

Once cleansed, all the people that are working on the stones will be freed, and you will also [gain an ability](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:All-Maker_Stones) from it. The Beast Stone in particular will allow you to summon a were-bear to fight along side you for a short time.

Additionally, the trigger for yourself to somehow have been entranced by the powers of the stone, and wake up worshipping/working on the stone is caused by sleeping in Solstheim before having learned the first word of the Bend Will shout.